# How to See Log or Sysout in Flink Standalone

Tags: apache-flink

I run my application in Flink standalone, but can't find it's sysout in console or `FLINK_HOME/log`.

Does anyone know where I can see my application debug log? And how to know which TMs my application run on?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When running a Flink application in standalone mode on a cluster, everything that is logged to system out or system err goes into the respective **local** `log/` directories.
So for getting the logs, you have to connect (for example using SSH) to the machines running TaskManagers and retrieve the logs from there.

> And how to know which TMs my application run on.

The JobManager web interface (running on host:8081 by default) shows where the tasks are deployed to.
When the parallelism == number of slots, the tasks usually run on all machines.